# TypeScript error when I perform addition to a number and pass as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a heading component which takes a level as a prop:

In Heading.tsx

```
type Props = {
  level?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
  children: string;
};
```

My other component needs to add a number to a prop it's given, and make that the level:

In MyComponent.tsx:

```
type Props = {
  componentLevel: 1 | 2 | 3;
};

const MyComponent = ({ componentLevel }) => (
  <Heading level={componentLevel + 1}>My Component Heading text</Heading>
)
```

Logically I can see that `Heading` will always get the props that it needs, however TypeScript gives me an error:

> TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript isn't able to tell that if you take something of type `1 | 2 | 3` and add one to it then it's type becomes `2 | 3 | 4`. Instead, the result is just a `number`, which is too broad for what Heading is expecting. You will need to assert that it's the correct type.

```
<Heading level={(componentLevel + 1) as 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6}>My Component Heading text</Heading>
```

You might want to give this type an alias so it's easier to refer to:

```
type HeadingLevel = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6

type Props = {
  level?: HeadingLevel,
  children: string
}

// ... 
<Heading level={(componentLevel + 1) as HeadingLevel}>My Component Heading text</Heading>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

In Heading.tsx

```
type HeadingProps = {
  level?: HeadingLevel;
  children: string;
};

type HeadingLevel = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
```

In MyComponent.tsx

```
<Heading level={(componentLevel + 1) as HeadingLevel}>My Component Heading text</Heading>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers already but I believe in this case you may be best to try and clearly delimit which values are possible; you aren't able to have typescript compute the possible types more specifically than `number` through the addition, so realistically the best you can do is:

```js
type ComponentLevel = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
type HeadingLevel = 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 6 | 7;

const componentToHeadingLevel: (c: ComponentLevel) => HeadingLevel = c => c + 1 as HeadingLevel;
```

You might want to think of the type number as `1 | 2 | 3`... etc. and so really we're just clearly defining what we want in the type.

Answer (score 0):

Other people's code is good answer, I just want to add some more detail:
When you use union like this : `level?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;` and then pass `level={componentLevel + 1}` as props of `Heading` component, TS only can understand `componentLevel + 1` as number because you did not mention that it is one value on the union `level?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;`.